# Electromagnetism Complete Induction

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I'm studying electromagnetism, but i'm not satisfied with the definition of complete induction.
For example my book talks about complete induction between two conductors when we consider that every line of electric field goes from the first to the second.

But how does this deal with the fact that we see an equal amount of charge on two conductor's extremities if between them a complete induction is instaurated?

And how does we determine in general if all the lines goes from the first to the second conductor?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you do not get "complete" induction.

However, that very clever man Faraday did find a way using an [ice pail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_ice_pail_experiment) and enclosing the inducing charge inside a hollow conductor on which charges were induced.

Comment: Yes but how i demonstrate that if there is  complete induction the amount of charges on the two surfaces are equal?

Comment: That was the whole point of Faraday’s ice pail experiment.